# Swift 3: How do i find the index of an object in an array?

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a protocol:

```
protocol MyProtocol : NSObjectProtocol {
    func MyProtocolUpdated()    
}
```

I have an array of protocols:

```
var delegates = Array<DataManagerDelegate>()
```

Now i want to remove a particular element from the array of protocols.
I'm guessing i have to use the
`delegates.remove(at: Int)`
method.

To do that, i try to find the index of the object using `delegates.index(of: delegate)`

```
But i'm getting the error "cannot invoke 'index' with an argument list of type '(of: MyProtocol)'"
```

How do i remove a specific object from the array??

Thanks

Comment: Keeping delegates in an array is not a very good idea. Delegates should be usually stored as `weak`, to prevent ownership cycles. Array always stores them as strong...

Answer (score 0):

one way to remove object from array in Swift is using functional programming.

```
delegates.filter({ $0  !=  objectThatYouwantToRemove })
```

this code will give an array which will not have your removing object.

Comment: I says `"Binary operator cannot be applied to two MyProtocol operands"`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index of an element with the `index(of: )` function. It returns an optional Int so you have to unwrap it. Your `DataManagerDelegate` has to conform to `Equatable`.

```
if let index = delegates.index(of: delegate) {
    delegates.remove(at: index)
}
```

Comment: But i'm getting the error `"cannot invoke 'index' with an argument list of type '(of: MyProtocol)'"` if i use `.index(of: )`

Comment: Does `MyProtoocol` conform to `Equatable`?

Comment: It doesn't (tried it by conforming it to `Equatable`), but shouldn't the Objects Conforming to `MyProtocol`, conform to `Equatable` as well? I don't want to make the adopters of MyProtocol conform to Equatable.

Comment: Does `DataManagerDelegate` conform to `Equatable`?

Answer (score 0):

In order to find an object from an array the object needs to conform to `Equatable`, so the array can compare the current item in the iteration to the one you're trying to find.

To do that, where you declare your protocol add:

`extension DataManagerDelegate: Equatable { }`

And then all your objects that conform to `DataManagerDelegate` will need to implement the

`static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool` function.

After that you should be able to find the index of an object.

Comment: Is there no way other than making the objects (that need to conform to  MyProtocol) implement the `static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool` function?

Comment: By default, not that I'm aware. If it doesn't conform to Equatable, then the array doesn't know how to check what is the correct element since it can't compare elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove an element from the array, you might use [Array.filter](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688383-filter).

```
protocol Shape {
  var name: String { get set }
}

struct Circle: Shape {
  var name = ""
}

struct Triangle: Shape {
  var name = ""
}
```

---

```
var shapes = Array<Shape>()

var circle1 = Circle(name: "circle1")
var triangle1 = Triangle(name: "triangle1")
var triangle2 = Triangle(name: "triangle2")

shapes.append(circle1)
shapes.append(triangle1)
shapes.append(triangle2)

// we want to remove the circle one so we filter it.
shapes = shapes.filter { $0.name != circle1.name }

print(shapes) 
// [Triangle(name: "triangle1"), Triangle(name: "triangle2")]
```

Comment: But what if i don't have any properties in MyProtocol, and just functions?